# How to integrate OAuth facebook login in Windows 8.1 Apps?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, facebook-oauth

I cannot find a simple library for integrating facebook oauth with windows 8.1 apps. 
Came accross facebook.net sdk but its far from compiling for v8.1.

Comment: Have you tried this? It seems easy :) http://blog.joefernandez.me/post/95027295518/facebook-login-on-windows-phone-81-windows

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own login flow. Facebook documents it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4).
There is also a specific section in the docs on [Windows Phone](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone)

Comment: Its pretty outdated :(

Comment: Please file a bug report for the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the WebAUthenticatorBroker combined with sdk provided by Facebook. The below link provides a detailed explanation for the same.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-FaceBook-87eb2f69